# jQuery: Synchronize begin/end of several divs in two column view

Tags: jquery, css, html

let's imagine a two column view. In the left column, you have city names and in the right one, there is the country belonging to these cities. Each Country would be in its own div.

```
----------------------  ---------------------- <div>  
Berlin  
________________________________________________ Screen Top  
Freiburg ----------- Germany  
Göttingen  
Hamburg  
Hannover  
München  
________________________________________________ Screen Bottom  

Xanten  
---------------------- ---------------------- </div>
```

As you can see from my draft above, there are much more entries in the div of the left column that there are on the right. The number of cities is so large that they do not fit onto one screen. I would now like to see the country as first line of the second column as long as the corresponding city names are displayed. If I keep on scrolling and the first city of the next country shows up, it should be exchanged by its country name. So, the end and starting points of the divs need to be synchronised but there might be a large number of divs under each other.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've come up with is at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CqnLc/2/) fiddle.

The way it works is you store all your cities and countries in divs with `class='item'`

Each has the following format:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="left">
        City 1 <br/>
        City 2 <br/>
        City 3 <br/>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Country Name
    </div>
</div> <!-- end item -->
```

Each country gets its own `item` div, populated with cities and the country name.

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var curChild = 1; // Which country is currently top of the parent div

$('.main').scroll(function () {
    // curChildBottom is the location of the bottom of curChild, with
    // respect to the top of the parent div
    var curChildBottom = $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ')').position().top + $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ')').height();

    // scrollStop is the location at which the country name no longer moves
    var scrollStop = curChildBottom - $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').height();

    // scrollValue is the current scroll bar position
    // Note: negative because .position().top gives a negative value when scrolled up
    var scrollValue = -($('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ')').position().top - 1);

    // If .right has reached the bottom of .item
    if (scrollStop < 0) {
        $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').css('top', 'auto');
        $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').css('bottom', '0px');
        // If the current child is no longer visible within parent div
        if (curChildBottom <= 0) {
            curChild++;
        }
    } else {
        $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').css('bottom', 'auto');
        $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').css('top', scrollValue);

        if (scrollValue < 0) {
            $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').css('bottom', 'auto');
            $('.main .item:nth-child(' + curChild + ') .right').css('top', '0px');
            if (curChild > 1) {
                curChild--;
            }

        }
    }
});
```

The script works by changing the position of the `right` div, which has an absolute position within its parent div (view [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqnLc/2/)).  Note that the `.item` MUST have `position: relative;` as a CSS property.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried it and it's working. I now need to adapt the approach to my application. Regards